# How magento determine the css theme folder in custom module

Tags: magento-1, css

I have a custom module, which will add skin css

```
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/banner.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

finally it includes the css for me in base theme

```
http://localhost/m1/skin/frontend/base/default/css/banner.css
```

How can I make it load the css in current theme?

Comment: if you put your css in your current theme magento theme fall back will do it accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your css in your current theme like:

`skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/css/banner.css`

Comment: need to change layout syntax? seems cannot use additem and type if apply for solution

Comment: no need to change syntex... it is proper

Comment: if i change to <name>css/banner.css</name> to skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/banner.css, the path is duplicated
http://localhost/m1/skin/frontend/base/default/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/banner.css

Comment: you have to set <name>css/banner.css</name> only, it willtake css form your current theme. if magento doesn't find css in current therm then it collects from base

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an extension and using css/js then you have to include in base/default package because when you give your extension someone else at that time you dont know which theme they are using .

That's why magento provide fallback mechanism so if you developing an extension then you have to use last fallback so your files always pickup and user can override your files by adding in own theme.

Hope this will help your concern